# How do I, a warlock, deal with material components?

Tags: class-feature

So it’s my first time playing and I chose a Warlock. Is a component pouch more useful than arcane focus? Another question is that when I looked at the options in arcane focus, one of the options is arcane focus, so what does that mean?

Comment: What edition of D&D are you playing? We can't answer the question until we know both the system (D&D as you've already specified in this case) *and* the edition.

Comment: Welcome! Which edition of D&D are you playing? You can [edit] the question to include the corresponding tag such as [dnd-5e] or [dnd-4e]